# Is Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process differentiable?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

A stochastic process $X(t)$ is differentiable stochastically, in $L^p$ or almost surely by definition iff:

$$\lim\limits_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0}\frac{X(t+\Delta t)-X(t)}{\Delta t}=X'(t)$$

for each $t$  in the corresponding sense, where $X'(t)$ is another stochastic process (see [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Stochastic_process,_differentiable) ).

Is the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process differentiable stochastically or in $L^p$ or almost surely? How to prove this?

Comment: Can you add some references for this definition of the derivative of a stochastic process? Thanks

Comment: It's quite standard. I added it.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't -- the OU process is as rough as standard Brownian motion.

In fact, the defining SDE of the OU process shows that the variance of the difference quotient at any given $t$ diverges as $\Delta t \to 0$.

Comment: Could you please specify better the proof (if it is simple enough)? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Antonio write the difference as an integral (as per the definition of SDE) and see where it takes you